# How to convert day (day of the week) and time as string to different Timezones in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime

I have to convert a various amount of strings in to the local timezone (`.ToLocalTime()`) but unlike a normal DateTime string those strings only contain day and time (they are supposed to be in UTC) like so:

```
SUNDAY:17:00 
FRIDAY:16:50
MONDAY:20:50
THURSDAY:07:00
```

I am looking for a clever way to "convert" those strings to the local Timezone but since I can not get a DateTime out of this I would have to do it manually which I would like to avoid. (also I would not like to split the string... )

Comment: Don't use DateTime at all, use DateTimeOffset with an explicit offset. After all, Json also uses offsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot handle TimeZoneOffset correctly without knowing the exact date, because the offset may change from one day to the other (DST vs non-DST).

Getting the correct time is the easy part (if you have the correct date), just use the appropriate constructor of DateTime.

```
DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, System.DateTimeKind kind)
```

and specify the kind as `System.DateTimeKind.Utc`. Then you have your timestamp as a UTC time and you can then use `ToLocalTime()` to get the correct time in your local timezone.

The hard part seems to me, is getting the correct date out of your data. Which SUNDAY is meant, the next one (ie 2016-07-10) or the last one (2016-07-03)? This is especially important for dates near the switch of DST because this may result in different timestamps.

Also be aware that 'SUNDAY:23:00' UTC may become 'MONDAY:01:00' (and vice versa) for some timezones! So you'll have to do the calculation of the date also based on UTC and not your local time. For instance, if in local time it's Monday 2016-07-04 01:00, but this is Sunday 2016-07-03 23:00 in UTC then interpreting a timestamp SUNDAY:17:00 using the local time (and wanting the next sunday) will result in 2016-07-10 19:00 instead of 2016-07-03 19:00.

Comment: well those time string `SUNDAY:17:00` is always at UTC at the current time. So the exact date is always DateTime.UtcNow. Therefore davids approach will work, right?

Comment: How can it always be now if it is on different days?

Comment: yea that was a bit misleading. Its always from the perspective of the current date which is `UtcNow`. So when I am looking today at those strings where today is 05.07.2016 those strings are the "next" days

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DateTime Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a date and convert it like a normal DateTime, no?

Check this example, and replace with what you need.

```
var theDate = new DateTime (DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, hours, minute, second);
```

From the doc:

```
public DateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day
)

DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());
// The example displays the following output:
//      8/18/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: well I thought I can somehow avoid to split the string, get the time and convert it to int to get the `DateTime`.